# Suggestions on how to perform call center task

Tags: evaluating-civicrm

I know there is always more than one way to accomplish the same task, and as I am still very new to CiviCRM, I am looking for suggestions for possible workflows.

We have several fundraising teams that go out every weekend to raise money for our organization by setting up tables and selling items in front of stores. We have a team of several people and their job is to call the stores and try to book these spots.

We need to help the call team better manage and track what they are doing, which looks something like this:

(1) A store is identified and call team member calls and asks to speak to the manager about booking a date for our team to come out. Need to obviously track who called, who did they talk to, what is the address of the store.

(2) Several outcomes can happen: (i) booking is approved (ii) booking is rejected (iii) could not get thru to anybody (iv) we are asked to call back (v) somebody will call back

(3) Need to keep notes of every call/converstation and what happened, as well as add notes about what happened the day of the booking when the fundraising team was there.

This is pretty general idea of what happens, but gives you an idea of what we are trying to do.

Any suggestions appreciated.

Thanks

EDIT: Note I am using CicvCRM with WordPress.

Comment: I would aim to do this purely using Activities, new Activity Statuses and Custom fields on the Activity. Seems like it should cover the requirement for storing the data. in terms of then having displays of Activities based on Assignee and/or Status then if you are WP the best hope is SearchKit I suspect

Comment: Activities are probably the easiest solution, but perhaps you should also give CiviCase a go, just to compare and decide if the simplicity of Activities suits you best or the workflow approach of CiviCase is more to your liking.